# Jquery submit handler with two button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, submit

I have an issue.
I have created a form input with jQuery validation and I submit it using Ajax.
I have no problem using one submit handler, but how can do it using two buttons?

**The button**

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="SAVE CONTINUE" name="SC" id='SC' class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-shadow" data-role="button">
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="SAVE FINISH" name="SF" id='SF' class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-shadow" data-role="button">
        </td>
</table>
```

and  **action**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkConnection();
        $("#FORMX").validate({
                //errorClass:'myClass',
                rules: {
                    PRODUK: {
                        required: true
                        //NOSYMBOL: false
                    },
                    SHIFT:{
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    PRODUK: {
                        required: "Barang belum terisi"
                    },
                    SHIFT:{
                        required: "Shift belum dipilih"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST", 
                        url: "adonan_action.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO=tipe",
                        success: function(data){
                            //alert(data);
                            //if($.trim(php_script_response) == "sukses"){
                            if(data.status == "sukses"){
                                alert('Input Berhasil');
                                //window.location='logout.php';
                            }
                            else if(data.status == 'gagal'){
                                alert("Error on query!");
                            }
                       },
                    });//end ajax
                }
           });//end validate
        });//end ready function
```

How can I handle the button `id="SF"` ?
I have tried like this and it doesn't work.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#SC").on("click", function(){
        var tipe = "SC";
    });
    $("#SF").on("click", function(){
        var tipe = "SF";
    });
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        url: "adonan_action.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO=tipe",
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            //if($.trim(php_script_response) == "sukses"){
            if(data.status == "sukses"){
                alert('Input Berhasil');
                //window.location='logout.php';
            }
            else if(data.status == 'gagal'){
                alert("Error on query!");
            }
            },
        });//end ajax
```

All I need is to catch different `id` or values from buttons and I will send it with ajax to another Page.
Anyone can Help this?

Comment: You should probably pass the id of the button instead to the form when you click either of them instead. Doing `var tipe` inside those functions won't allow you access to them. Anyway if you wanted to access `tipe` you would do `data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO" + tipe"` instead as your current one is always going to put `KOPLO` as string `tipe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve it, like this

```
    $("#SC").on("click", function(){

                //var BTN = "SC";

                if($("#FORMX").valid()){
                     $.ajax({
                               type:"POST", 
                                url: "produksi_action.php",
                                dataType: "json",
                               data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO=SC",

                               success: function(data){

                                   alert(data);
                                  //if($.trim(php_script_response) == "sukses"){

                                   if(data.status == "sukses"){
                                         alert('Input Berhasil');

                                    }
                                    else if(data.status == 'gagal'){
                                         alert("Error on query!");
                                    } 
                               },error:function(dt){
                                   alert("error");
                               }


                            });//end ajax
                }
                else{

                    alert('Tolong Lengkapi Kolom yang Kosong..!');

                }






            });//end click



            $("#SF").on("click", function(){

                //var BTN = "SC";

                if($("#FORMX").valid()){
                     $.ajax({
                               type:"POST", 
                                url: "produksi_action.php",
                                dataType: "json",
                               data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO=SF",

                               success: function(data){

                                   alert(data);
                                  //if($.trim(php_script_response) == "sukses"){

                                   if(data.status == "sukses"){
                                         alert('Input Berhasil');

                                    }
                                    else if(data.status == 'gagal'){
                                         alert("Error on query!");
                                    } 
                               },error:function(dt){
                                   alert("error");
                               }


                            });//end ajax
                }
                else{

                    alert('Tolong Lengkapi Kolom yang Kosong..!');

                }






            });//end click
```

No Need Submit Handler.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the following code you can find which button is clicked. Is this what you wanted??
1. Create a global variable, in following code it's btnClicked
2. in html mark up, add onlclick so that btnClicked is changed when btn isclicked
3. Access this btnClicked variable in Ur submit handler

Refer below code!!!!

```js
submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert(btnClicked); //Here in thi variable you can find the id of the btn clicked :)
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "adonan_action.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $("#FORMX").serialize() + "&KOPLO=tipe",
      success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        //if($.trim(php_script_response) == "sukses"){
        if (data.status == "sukses") {
          alert('Input Berhasil');
          //window.location='logout.php';
        } else if (data.status == 'gagal') {
          alert("Error on query!");
        }
      },
    }); //end ajax
```

```html
<script>
  var btnClicked = "";
</script>
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="SAVE CONTINUE" name="SC" id='SC' onclick="btnClicked = 'SC'" class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-shadow" data-role="button">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="SAVE FINISH" name="SF" id='SF' onclick="btnClicked = 'SF'" class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-shadow" data-role="button">
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, have Try your Advice, work only on id="SF", or Second Button, but on first Button alert not Showing value. Anything Wrong?